# Is there a way to change the output row name in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have Procedure which removed/deleted the lowest lnr. The code works fine.

```
SELECT * FROM lager; -- Before

CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE del_min_lager AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Lagerbuchung
    WHERE  LNR = (SELECT MIN(LNR) FROM Lager);
    DELETE FROM Lager
    WHERE  LNR = (SELECT MIN(LNR) FROM Lager);
END del_min_lager;
/

EXECUTE del_min_lager;
SELECT * FROM Lager; -- After
```

So my question is, if there is anyway I can make my output better.

I've tried following:

```
SELECT * FROM Lager as 'Before';
```

But it doesn't work like it does in **SSMS**.

I would like to have output such as:

```
BEFORE
.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Use double quotes, or don't quote at all. And that's the same in SQL Server (I assume that's what you mean by SSMS, which is the client app)

Comment: I've tried also with double quotes didn't work for me.

Comment: Didn't work meaning...?

Comment: @Charlieface I've tried `select * from lager as "Before"` and that didn't work, but thanks to @scaisEdge it works now.

Comment: That's an entirely different question, how to get the same value in every row? You seemed to be asking for a column name/header

Comment: @Charlieface I'm sorry, maybe my question wasn't understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add  a column for status

```
SELECT 'BEFORE' AS status, lager.* FROM lager
```